# how to put each element into array separately that is already inside an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have some data basically what i want to do is to put each element inside it into an array separately

```
array (size=4112)
  'new Date('2018-09-22 00:00:11')' => float 22.2148
  'new Date('2018-09-22 00:00:33')' => float 22.2154
  'new Date('2018-09-22 00:00:55')' => float 22.2094
  'new Date('2018-09-22 00:01:16')' => float 22.1987
  'new Date('2018-09-22 00:01:35')' => float 22.2005
  'new Date('2018-09-22 00:01:43')' => float 22.1914
  'new Date('2018-09-22 00:01:59')' => float 22.2025
  'new Date('2018-09-22 00:02:20')' => float 22.1882
  'new Date('2018-09-22 00:02:54')' => float 22.1864
           ....
```

How can i put each 'new Date('2018-09-22 00:00:11')' => float 22.2148 into another array in php?

This was code

```
foreach($unitTelemetryData1 as $device) {
    array_shift($device);//RemoveTimeSTAMP
    foreach($device as $key => $value)
    {
        //echo $key ." ".$value;
        $tempX = array_column($unitTelemetryData1,$key,$TimeStamp);
        array_push($result,$tempX);

    }
    break;
}

//var_dump($result);
//die();


foreach($result as $r)
{

    $result1 = array('series'=>array('name' => $serial, 'data' => $r));
    array_push($result2,$result1);
    //break;
}
```

see last foreach $r does contain key and value

Comment: `$arr = ['key' => value]`

Comment: can you explain according to above code

Comment: The array shown above is what you have or what you want?

Comment: what is shown what i want is $r has a list of arrays containing 'new Date('2018-09-22 00:00:11')' => float 22.2148 but as array

Comment: I think you want https://3v4l.org/ciIQm